# transpile ionic serve runs but build fails

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

The transpile task for ionic build fails with.

> [09:56:34]  build dev failed: Maximum call stack size exceeded

The ionic serve task, shows this message when run. But when the watcher fires a new transpile it works.

Is there a difference in how the transpile task works, when invoked via watcher?

Comment: did u try running with ionic run android --l --c

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution- 
execute this command

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: I get this output:
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
sysctl: illegal option -- p
usage: sysctl [-bdehiNnoqx] name[=value] ...
       sysctl [-bdehNnoqx] -a

I'm running on OSX 10.12.1